# Ejecutar $.ajax dentro de un ciclo

Tags: javascript, ajax, ciclos

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código, deseo ir ejecutando dentro de un ciclo `for` una llamada `$.ajax` hasta que se cumpla la condición de salida del ciclo, sin embargo el ciclo hace todas sus iteraciones y en la iteración final ejecuta el `ajax`, por lo que no logro conseguir el efecto que necesito en mi algoritmo.

```
var streamers = ["qt314g", "feelinkgamer", "brunofin", "streamerhouse"];
var urljoin = "";

for (k in streamers){
  urljoin = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamers[k] + "?client_id=1t2i1eidglzctkjlx1xckdtguuj0y2z";
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urljoin,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "twitchcallback"
  });
}

function twitchcallback(json) {
  alert(json["_links"]["self"]);
  if(k>=streamers.length-1){
     alert("Finished");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Este es un problema muy recurrente que noto que tienen los desarrolladores, las llamadas Ajax como otras operaciones I/O son operaciones asíncronas en javascript, puedes leer otras preguntas relacionadas con este tema, una manera de lidiar con el flujo de ejecución de operaciones asíncronas es con el uso de promises.

Utilizando Promises.all puedes ejecutar una pila de promises y obtener el resultado cuando todos se han ejecutado, entonces.

```js
var streamers = ["qt314g", "feelinkgamer", "brunofin", "streamerhouse"];
var urljoin = "";
var requests = []; // Pila de solicitudes

for (k in streamers){
  urljoin = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamers[k] + "?client_id=1t2i1eidglzctkjlx1xckdtguuj0y2z";
  requests.push(
 $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: urljoin,
      dataType: "jsonp"
    })
  )
}

Promise.all(requests).then(streamersValues => { 
  streamersValues.forEach( streamer => console.log(streamer["_links"]["self"]));
  alert('Terminado!')
});
```

Mas conciso

```
var streamers = ["qt314g", "feelinkgamer", "brunofin", "streamerhouse"];
var urljoin = "";

var requests = streamers.map(streamer => {
  urljoin = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamer + "?client_id=1t2i1eidglzctkjlx1xckdtguuj0y2z";
  return (
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: urljoin,
      dataType: "jsonp"
    })
  )
})

Promise.all(requests).then(streamersValues => { 
  streamersValues.forEach( streamer => console.log(streamer["_links"]["self"]));
  alert('Terminado!')
});
```

Sin utilizar el operador arrow

```
var streamers = ["qt314g", "feelinkgamer", "brunofin", "streamerhouse"];
var urljoin = "";

var requests = streamers.map(function(streamer) {
  urljoin = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamer + "?client_id=1t2i1eidglzctkjlx1xckdtguuj0y2z";
  return (
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: urljoin,
      dataType: "jsonp"
    })
  )
})

Promise.all(requests).then(function(streamersValues) { 
  streamersValues.forEach( function(streamer) {
    console.log(streamer["_links"]["self"])
  });

  alert('Terminado!')
});
```

Comment: Una pregunta. De donde sale streamersValues, streamer? Y no recuerdo bien lo que era pero el =>{} es como poner function(){] en ecmascript 7? Me suena de algo pero hace tiempo que no toco...

Comment: @Lorthas edite la respuesta para agregar el mismo ejemplo sin utilizar el operador Arrow, espero haber despejado la duda.

Comment: Utilizando un scope local (`let`) podría tener el mismo efecto. Hay que tener en cuenta que `Promise.all` se resolverá satisfactoriamente **solo si todas las operaciones** se han ejecudado correctamente. Si al menos una falla, entonces, lo que hará será **rechazar** la promesa principal (all) y las promesas pendientes serán descartadas.

Comment: Con let o una función anónima no resolverías el problema de controlar el flujo del código asíncrono, en cuanto a Promises.all es cierto que al fallar un solo promise interno falla la ejecución de la pila pero ya eso depende del requerimiento del problema en concreto y como tiene pensado manejar esta situación que no está especificada en la pregunta

Comment: Sí, tienes razón, ya vi su jsonp callback abajo y lo que hace. En la app de Android no se ve bien el code ¬¬. La mejor opción es usar async/await, la mejor forma de escribir código asíncrono como si fuese síncrono, claro, si lo soportasen lo suficiente los navegadores xD. Nada que no se pueda resolver con babel.

Comment: Wow, muchas gracias Carlos, aun no pruebo tu solucion pero creo que esto es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Cuando termine la implementacion del codigo (Que es algo un poco mas complejo que esta version resumida que improvise para simplificar mi duda, les dare los resultados)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar crear una función para hacer tu llamada `AJAX` y que de este modo tenga un poco más de "independencia" a la hora de la ejecución:

```
var streamers = ["qt314g", "feelinkgamer", "brunofin", "streamerhouse"];
var urljoin = "";

for (k in streamers){
    urljoin = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamers[k] + "?client_id=1t2i1eidglzctkjlx1xckdtguuj0y2z";
    myAjaxCall(urljoin);
}

function myAjaxCall(urljoin){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: urljoin,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "twitchcallback"
    });
}

function twitchcallback(json) {
    alert(json["_links"]["self"]);
    if(k >= streamers.length-1){
        alert("Finished");
    }
}
```

Si estás trabajando con `jQuery` lo más sencillo y recomendable sería hacer uso del `$.each` de la siguiente forma:

```
var streamers = ["qt314g", "feelinkgamer", "brunofin", "streamerhouse"];
var urljoin = "";

$.each(streamers, function(index, streamer){
    urljoin = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamer + "?client_id=1t2i1eidglzctkjlx1xckdtguuj0y2z";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: urljoin,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "twitchcallback"
    });
}

function twitchcallback(json) {
    alert(json["_links"]["self"]);
    if(k >= streamers.length-1){
        alert("Finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ejecutando los dos ejemplos, ninguno logra el comportamiento deseado

Comment: Buenas Naos. La verdad es que ya he intentado este par de opciones antes, y tambien bastantes otras variaciones, pero ninguna ha funcionado. Estoy por probar las que me han ofrecido aca. Gracias por tu interes!

Answer (score 0):

```
var streamers = ["qt314g", "feelinkgamer", "brunofin", "streamerhouse"];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamers[i] + "?client_id=1t2i1eidglzctkjlx1xckdtguuj0y2z",
            data:{},
            dataType: "jsonp",
            type:"GET",
            beforeSend: function(){
            },
            success: function(rs){
                //Tu código aquí
                alert(rs);
            },
            error: function(er1, er2, er3){
                alert(er1+" "+er2+" "+er3);
            }
        });

        if(i>=streamers.length){
            alert("Finished");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Tengo un problema con el siguiente código, *deseo ir ejecutando dentro de un ciclo for una llamada $.ajax hasta que se cumpla la condición de salida del ciclo*, sin embargo el ciclo hace todas sus iteraciones y en la iteración final ejecuta el ajax.

Según lo que yo entiendo, tu objetivo es que por cada iteración ejecutar una petición ajax. Y lo que obtienes, es que tu código hace la petición en la última iteración. Antes de continuar, es importante lo siguiente:

> JavaScript es un lenguaje **asíncrono**, lo que significa que no hay un orden de ejecución fijo en el que puedas confiar. No todas las características del lenguaje son bloqueantes, hay algunas que sí pero la gran mayoría no. como es el caso de peticiones ajax.

Siempre te encontrarás en que estás ejecutando procesos en paralelo y no sabes cómo actuar. En ES5, era muy común ver éste tipo de errores de programadores que venían de lenguajes no funcionales. Con la llegada de ES6 solucionas gran parte de éste inconveniente con ayuda de [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promesa), [block scopes](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-block-level-scoping-let-const/) y en la próxima versión, [Async/Await](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await).

**ES5**

La solución antes de ES6+ era utilizar un closure dentro del loop para crear un scope para la variable de control:

```
for (var s of streamers) {
  (function(s) {
    $.ajax({
      url: `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/${s}?client_id=1t2i1eidglzctkjlx1xckdtguuj0y2z`,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonCallback: 'twitchcallback'
    })
    .done(data => {
      console.log(`Streamer ${s} complete`);
      console.log(data);

      if (s === streamers[streamers.length - 1]) {
        alert('finished');
      }
    });
  })(s);
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guzgarcia/rmsLghxo/)

**ES6**

Solucionarlo en ES6 es mucho más sencillo. Solo basta usar un scope local en lugar de un global como lo es `var`:

```
for (let s of streamers) {
  $.ajax({
    url: `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/${s}?client_id=1t2i1eidglzctkjlx1xckdtguuj0y2z`,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonCallback: 'twitchcallback'
  })
  .done(data => {
    console.log(`Streamer ${s} complete`);
    console.log(data);

    if (s === streamers[streamers.length - 1]) {
      alert('finished');
    }
  });
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guzgarcia/ypyc7fc9/)

**ES Next: Async/Await**

Con async await puedes controlar el flujo de manera mucha más natural si vienes de lenguajes no funcionales. El código escrito con `async/await` sigue siendo asíncrono aunque lo escribamos de forma síncrona.

> **Nota:** Para hacer uso de `await` se debe estar en una función marcada con `async`

```
(async () => {
    for (let s of streamers) {
    const data = await (
      $.ajax({
        url: `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/${s}?client_id=1t2i1eidglzctkjlx1xckdtguuj0y2z`,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonCallback: 'twitchcallback'
      })
    );
    console.log(`Streamer ${s} complete`);
    console.log(data);
    if (s === streamers[streamers.length - 1]) {
      alert('finished');
    }
  }
})();
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guzgarcia/hrn7pk2L/)

Si decides usar la tercera forma debes usar [babel](https://babeljs.io):

```
babel archivo.js destino.js
```

Comment: En tus dos primeros ejemplos el código sigue siendo asíncrono y el alert puede mostrarse antes de que cualquiera de las peticiones termine, el ultimo ejemplo funciona perfecto

Comment: En los tres ejemplos sigue siendo asíncrono y sip, en los ejemplos 1 y 2 el mensaje de finalizado puede variar a diferencia de async/await que es un control limpio. La idea del código ES5 y ES6 es mostrar que se puede realizar una petición por cada item del array. El OP no especificó que quería hacerlos en un orden fijo. En ese caso haría peticiones síncronas o usaría async/await de preferencia.

Comment: Gracias guzgarcia, en especial por la explicacion acerca de Javascript siendo un lenguaje asincrono, la verdad es que comence a aprender este lenguaje por cuenta propia hace poco tiempo, y veo que aun hay cosas basicas que me falta aprender.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es hacerlo en serie hasta encontrar un streamer con algún contenido o estructura particular es algo así:

```
var streamers = ["qt314g", "feelinkgamer", "brunofin", "streamerhouse"];
function requestStreamers(streamers, callback){
    var urljoin = "";
    var current = 0;
    streamers = streamers || [];
    function nextRequest(){
        if(streamers[current]){
            urljoin = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamers[current] + "?client_id=1t2i1eidglzctkjlx1xckdtguuj0y2z";
            $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: urljoin,
              dataType: "jsonp",
              jsonpCallback: function(json){
                  if(true /*condición que debe cumplir*/){
                      callback(null, json);
                  } else {
                      nextRequest();
                  }
              }
            });
        } else {
            callback(new Error("No useful stream found"));
        }
    }
}
```

Pero si lo que quieres solo es hacer la petición a todos, pasan dos cosas, k siempre será 3 en tu ejemplo poruqe para cuando llega el primer callback, el for ya ha terminado, la segunda es que no puedes garantizar que la última request sea la última en responder, es posible que por temas de server, la primera te responda al final, o a la mitad, etc, por lo que la mejor solución es esta:

```
var streamers = ["qt314g", "feelinkgamer", "brunofin", "streamerhouse"];
var urljoin = "";
var requestsFinished = 0;

for (k in streamers){
    urljoin = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamers[k] + "?client_id=1t2i1eidglzctkjlx1xckdtguuj0y2z";
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: urljoin,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      jsonpCallback: "twitchcallback"
    });
}

function twitchcallback(json) {
  requestsFinished ++;
  alert(json["_links"]["self"]);
  if(requestsFinished >= streamers.length){
     alert("Finished");
  }
}
```